# Список из лямбд, реализующих функциональный интерфейс

Tags: java, lambda, очередь-задач

Чисто для саморазвития.

Допустим стоит задача создать список из простых, но различных действий, который сперва наполним, а потом начнем выполнять (например после выполнения некоего длительного асинхронного процесса).

Интерфейс:

```
public interface DelayedAction {
    void makeAction();
}
```

Основной код:

```
List<DelayedAction> delayedAction = new ArrayList<>();
delayedAction.add(()->System.out.println("YES"));

veryLongAsyncProcess(()->{
    for (DelayedAction current : delayedAction) {
        current.makeAction();
    }
    delayedAction.clear();
});

delayedAction.add(()->map.refresh());
delayedAction.add(()->sendRequest(url));
```

Чем может быть плох такой подход? 
(ну кроме того, что выполнение может начаться раньше наполнения - это понятно и решаемо).

Как правильно решать такие задачи?

Можно ли чудесным образом заинлайнить функциональный интерфейс внутрь List (как нибудь через Consumer например)?

Comment: У меня ощущение, что конкретно в данном примере вам скорее нужна очередь

Comment: ну это уже детали того, как нам потом с этим набором работать.

Comment: Выглядит как попытка изобрести заново `j.u.c.ExecutorService`